# Linear differential equation system and general variation of parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus, differential

I need some feedback to complete my solution for the following exercise:

Given a matrix $ A\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ and a vector $ b\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$, take a look at the initial value problem (IVP)

$$ y'=Ay+b\quad\land\quad y(0)=y_{0}\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$$

Determine the solution for the IVP by using variation of parameters. Calculate the
occurring integral explicitly in case of $ b\in\operatorname{img}(A)$.

Well, one can find $y(x)=\mathrm{e}^{xA}y_{0}$ as solution for the homogeneous differential equation. Now using the method of variation of parameters by inserting $ y(x)=\mathrm{e}^{xA}y_{0}(x)$ in the system and knowing that the matrix exponential is invertible

\begin{align}
 &&A\mathrm{e}^{xA}y_{0}(x)+\mathrm{e}^{xA}y_{0}'(x) &= A\mathrm{e}^{xA}y_{0}(x)+b \\
\Leftrightarrow && \mathrm{e}^{xA}y_{0}'(x) &= b\\
\Leftrightarrow && y_{0}'(x) &=\mathrm{e}^{-xA}b \\
\Leftrightarrow && y_{0}(x) &= y_{0} + \left(\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{e}^{-tA}b\mathrm{d}t\right)
\end{align}
How to go on from that point onwards? Can I do something like that or?
\begin{align}
\overset{?}{\Rightarrow} && y_{0}(x) &= y_{0} + \left(\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{e}^{-tA}\mathrm{d}t\right)b \\
\Leftrightarrow && y_{0}(x) &= y_{0}+A^{-1}b\mathrm{e}^{-xA}
\end{align}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stumbled evaluating the integral in the last step.
$$\eqalign{
d\left(e^{-tA}\right) &= -Ae^{-tA}dt \\
e^{-xA}-I &= \int_{0}^{x}-Ae^{-tA}dt \\
A^{-1}(I-e^{-xA}) &= \int_{0}^{x}e^{-tA}dt \\
}$$
Using the function
$$\phi(x) = \frac{e^x-1}{x}$$
this result can be written as
$$\eqalign{
\int_{0}^{x}e^{-tA}dt
&= \phi(-xA)\;x \\
}$$
And your variational approach yields
$$\eqalign{
y_0(x) &= y_0 + \phi(-xA)\left(xb\right) \\
y(x) &= e^{xA}y_0  + \phi(xA)\left(xb\right) \\
}$$